# Rbind dataframes using wildcard

Tags: r, wildcard, rbind

Suppose I have three dataframes called A1-pre, B3-pos, B4-pre and I want to merge these dataframes. The columns have the same name, so I can use rbind.

```
newdf <- rbind(A1-pre, B3-pos, B4-pre)  #this would work
```

However, I do not want to manually input all the names of the dataframes myself, I rather use a wildcard for that, so something like

```
newdf <- rbind(grep(-)) #but this does not work
```

Any idea how I could do that? Or even better, matching any dataframe named "pre" or "pos" and rbind them all.

Comment: You really named your `data.frame`s with a `-` in the name? Look into using `ls()`, `do.call()`, and `get()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `get()` and `ls()`:

```
'A1-pre' <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5) 
'B3-pos' <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5)
'B4-pre' <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5)
'C5-not' <- matrix(rnorm(100), 5)

names <- grep('pre|pos$', ls(), value=T)

newDF <- mapply(get, grep('pre|pos$', ls(), value=T))
```

Comment: Or `do.call(rbind, lapply(ls(pattern = "-pre"), get))` and so on, as I was alluding to in my comment.