# rbind or cbind multiple matrices without entering all the object names

Tags: r, rbind, cbind

I have many (more than 20) matrices with the same dimension and sequential names like 'mat01', 'mat02', 'mat03', ... , 'mat20', etc.

Can I rbind or cbind all these matrices without typing every single matrix names?

Edit.
I need to revise my question.
The matrices are not yet in the R workspace. It is separate csv files in my local computer such as "c:/mat1.csv", "c:/mat2.csv".
Then the answer in the [Rbind dataframes using wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530779/rbind-dataframes-using-wildcard) does not apply.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21530779/rbind-dataframes-using-wildcard

Comment: @Pascal Please see my edit

Comment: Is there any way that I can notify the users nrussell, jbaums and the latemail who marked this as duplicate that I edited my question? Is this automatically notified?

Comment: Still a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11433432/importing-multiple-csv-files-into-r